# .toggle() getting called twice on single click

Tags: jquery

Why i am getting the alert "toggle complete" twice while calling .toggle() on clicking the "p" element. Below is the sample code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
      $("p").toggle( 'slow', function(){ 
                alert('toggel complete');                
               });

  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Toggle</button>

<p>This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
<p>This is another small paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `function(){alert(...)}` is a callback function which will be called for all `<p>` tags. Hence 2 alerts.

Answer (score 3):

You are adding a click event that affects all `<p>` tags. In your case, you're adding two events so your alert is being called twice as a result.

Answer (score 0):

There are two `'p'` elements in your code.
That's why `alert()` is displayed twice.